# problem with setVisibility when swithching between two ImageView elements in Java

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview

```
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(imageViewGet1.getDrawable() != null){
                imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imageViewGet1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            OpenGallery1();

        }
    });
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(imageViewGet2.getDrawable() != null){
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imageViewGet2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            OpenGallery2();

        }
    });
```

when I run the code and open galley to pick new photo, after that, the imageView  with the old one still appear
how I can fix that so when I choose new image, the imageView1 disappear and imageViewGet appear with the new Image.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

if are views overlapping (one is in front of second).

```
.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

just makes view invisible, but doesn't hide it.

If this won't help, you may can use `Shared Preferences` to store `bool` with image (in)visibility state.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

```
imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                OpenGallery1();

                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imageViewGet1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(imageViewGet1.getDrawable()==null){
                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

and it works fine.